# Find out the Identity of the request sender - AJAX Auto Complete Extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete, code-reuse

this is a typical webMethod i am using as a dataSource for Ajax autoComplete Extender

```C#
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]

public static List<string> FontNamesList_AutoCompDataSrc(string prefixText)
{ 

    if (SeSn.CurrentSesionVariablsSet.FontList.Count == 0)
    {
        FntsList = ReflectMeths.anyClassFldsAsListByType<fntNamsClss>();

        SeSn.CurrentSesionVariablsSet.FontList = FontsList;
        SeSn.AddToCurrentSesseionVars(App.VariablesNames.FontsList,
            SeSn.CurrentSesionVariablsSet.Fontlist);
    }
    else
    {
        if (SeSn.VarExist(App.VariablesNames.FontsList))
             FontsList= SesnGetValAs.ListStr(App.VariableNames.FontsList);

        else FontsList= SeSn.CurrentSesionVariablsSet.FontList;
    }


    return AutoComplete.FromListStr(prefixText, FontsList);
}
```

so this method will serve the AutoCompleteExtendr in aspx page.

i would like to find out which one of the ajax AC Extenders was requesting the source,
so i could somehow use the same method for more than one control.

if i know *who* it is, I could `switch` on its identity and make some other actions ..based on the object that has requested the service .

i hope i am clear with my bad english ...

this is an example of a control on the `.aspx` file

```html
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolKitScrptMan1" runat="server"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>

<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" TargetControlID="TBX_FntsAC" runat="server"
                         MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1"
                         CompletionInterval="100" ServiceMethod="FontNamesList_AutoCompDataSrc" 
                         FirstRowSelected="true" CompletionListCssClass="CL_Css_DataBase" CompletionListItemCssClass="CL_ItemCss_DataBase" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="CL_tHighlightedItemCss_DataBase">
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

so if i have few of them with some different requests

all i need is to know which one of them was fired .

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `ContextKey` property, which can be used to pass additional information from the webpage to the web method.

The signature of the webmethod will have to be modified to accomodate the `ContextKey`.
Here - http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Comment: @shakalpesh **you are a life savior**, i bet not so many developers knew about it , i did look into it (this link for all parameters) though only when first worked with AC extender, and even now when you're telling me where to find the name of an existing parameter for exactly what i was looking for, it is not really well explaind " use this contextKey as your additional custom parameters ...etc" and give some examlple usage..., also i couldn't tell which keywords to use , i did use "c# asp.net catch ajax autocomplete callback" and many others tries for a search term...thanks !!

Comment: @LoneXcoder: I am happy to be of help. I haven't worked with AC extender. The way I found this is to look at properties and see if there is a way to do such a thing and `ContextKey` seemed to do what you are looking for.

Comment: @shakalpesh , it is then the experience in this world of programming , the ability to understand is yet to be concurred in my side ... i find it even hard to say what i mean.. basics you know having a look at it again , is like reviewing msdn explanations it is not real English . as i will tell you a tiger is a wiled beast when you don't know what a beast is , any ways looking at it again an again , it does not really directing a newbie developer as it's customers / audience, it's like that in many places , that is why i am Learning in tutorials and  nice ppl's blogs or article